# How to place a UI element in android , if i know its percentage height from bottom or top

Tags: android

I have to make a screen in android . and add some UI elements to it .
I want to know is there a way to add element on UI if i know at what percentage height from bottom that element is to be placed . And i know the size of the element in dp , like (32dp * 44 dp).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to calculate the height and width of device runtime and according to those figures you need to define your percentage height and width.
You can find the height and width at runtime as following

```
    displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` and `weight` param if you wish to set a percentage ratio

Example:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/one"
            android:id="@+id/view_1"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/two"
            android:id="@+id/view_2"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here `view_1` gets 80% of parent height and `view_2` gets 20%.

Comment: this is not what , i am looking for . I have % height of a ui element from all four directions (bottom ,top, right left)of screen . Is there any android Linear  or Relative Layout parameter , to provide these values , so that ui elment can be rendered based on these % values.